# Have to hold mouse button down to access menus with Xinerama enabled - can this be changed?

Tags: unity, nvidia, 16.04, menu, xinerama

I've got a Xinerama setup (3 monitors, 2 GPUs), and I'm using the default Ubuntu window manager.

Without Xinerama, the menu bar behaves one way: click once to drop the menu down, then click again on the option of interest. But with Xinerama enabled, it behaves differently: hold the mouse button to keep the menu dropped down, then release the button when the cursor is over the desired option.

I much prefer the non-Xinerama behaviour. Can I get it back?

(Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, NVIDIA driver 370.23)

Answer (score 1):

I discovered quite by accident that the old behaviour comes back after setting the `Show the menus for a window` option to `In the window's title bar` (System Settings, Appearance, Behaviour tab).

(I don't personally much mind where the menus are, making this workaround OK from my perspective.)